# How to Extract Values from a colon deliminated list (Oracle SQL)

Tags: oracle11g

I have a list of values being stored in a column of a table, and want to extract only certain values from this column

For example Project1 has the following stored in the column CVC_MATRIX

:4:7:6:8:10:12:14:16:17:

What I want to do is query the column, extract out any numbers between 14 and 22 (inclusive), and the assign a text value to these numbers.

For example, in the case where the stored value is :4:7:6:8:10:12:14:16:17: I would pull out only 14, 16 and 17 and convert the 14 to 'OTM' the 16 to 'Saves' and the 17 to 'TD'

So that what is displayed to the end user is OTM, Saves, TD

Does that make sense?